# Implementing pathfinding in R

Tags: r, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I am looking for an existing package that provides pathfinding algorithms for 2d data. I have a regular grid with scores and would like to start out with the A* algorithm.

I am surprised that there doesn't seem to be an R package dealing with such a task (obviously, googling for "a* algorithm in R" gives very unspecific results).

Does anyone know of an existing package and if there is none, can point me towards an efficient way of implementing the algorithm in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `e1071` and `igraph`. Not sure if they do A*, but they seem to have other shortest past algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! However, I just decided to implement it myself since I need to adapt the algorithm to certain things.

Comment: You always learn more when you implement yourself :).

Comment: However, I just hit a wall in R due to the recursion depth even at small map sizes... Switching back to python for that!

Comment: Ouchy. You could post anew and maybe someone could suggest an optimization.

Comment: You get anywhere? Now I am looking for the same thing. Although it is quite straightforward.